# Validate text field in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I have an array of object like who display 2 fields time and record :

```
sprint:[{time: void 0, record: void 0}]
```

```
<div v-for="(s, index) in sprint" :key="index">
    <v-text-field
        class="input"
        v-model="sprint.time"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="sprint.record"
    ></v-text-field> 
</div>
```

When I click on add button , I have a function who add these fields after:

```
            addSprint() {
                this.sprint.push({
                  time: '',
                  record: ''
              });
            },
```

I want use Vuelidate to check each of these if it's exist.
The validation must be field 
required, 
numeric , 
time: between 0 and 1( float 0.1 , 0.2, ..) ,
record : between 0 and 100,

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the the added validation to both the fields: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/eYYWGLe?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <div v-for="(s, index) in sprint" :key="index">
          Index: {{index}}
            <v-text-field
                class="input"
                label="time"
                :rules="[rules.required, rules.time]"
                v-model="s.time"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
                label="record"
                :rules="[rules.required, rules.record]"
                v-model="s.record"
            ></v-text-field> 
        </div>
        <v-btn @click="addSprint">Add Sprint</v-btn>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    sprint: [],
    rules: {
      required: v => !!v || 'this field is required',
      time: v => (v >= 0 && v <= parseFloat(1)) || "enter value less than 1 or greater than 0",
      record: v =>  (v >= 0 && v <= 100) || "enter value less than 100 or greater than 0",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSprint() {
                this.sprint.push({
                  time: '',
                  record: ''
              });
            },
  },
})
```